# In Javascript how to initialize a class containing a member variable of the same class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, recursion

I am having this puzzle. I am defining a class, which can have dynamical level of its replication. Think it as a expandable menu. Now I define it as:

```
class MyClass {
    name: string = '';
    fields: any[] = [];
    next_level: MyClass = NONE_TYPE;
}
```

So if there is a next level, I will assign it as:

```
next_level = new MyClass();
```

However, I was reminded that "Type 'BuiltinType' is missing the following properties from type 'MyClass': fields, ..."
So assigning it to NONE_TYPE in class initialization is not feasible. If I do so:

```
class MyClass {
...
   next_level: MyClass = new MyClass();
}
```

Compilation will allow it, but initializing such class will exhaust the stack as it can go on unlimitedly. So what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: How exactly do you expect it to make any sense? You have a type, and a property of type instances has a value of the same type. So how exactly is that not infinitely recursive?

Comment: On the first level, the next_level may point to a MyClass object, then within this object, the next_level can be NONE_TYPE, then it stops.

Comment: Well then don't unconditionally initialize the property.

Comment: What's `NONE_TYPE`?  What's `BuiltinType`? Could you provide a self-contained plaintext [mre] that we can copy as-is and paste into our own IDEs?  I'd say presumably `next_level` should be annotated as type `MyClass | typeof NONE_TYPE` but without a demonstrable example I can't be sure.

Comment: Can't you just make it `next_level?: MyClass` and leave it undefined until you give it a value?

Comment: @kelsny A [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) that implements an interface without doing anything can sometimes be useful to simplify code. But indeed that doesn't appear to be what the `NONE_TYPE` value did…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kelsny's answer works:

```
class MyClass {
    name: string = '';
    fields: any[] = [];
    next_level?: MyClass;
}
```

Or I have another workaround:

```
class MyClass {
    name: string = '';
    fields: any[] = [];
    next_level: MyClass[] = [];
}
```

The first is better.

Comment: Do not use an array where you expect zero or one, but never multiple, objects.